# Difference between major_compact on a table or on all regions of table

Tags: hbase

Say I have an Hbase table with 10 regions, Which is better approach to run major_compact on the table. To run major_compact on whole table via command:

> hbase> major_compact "tableName"

or running `major_compact` on all regions one after another(after major_compact of one region has completed)-

> hbase> major_compact "region1"

This I am asking so to make sure when running live compact there is no impact on production traffic. When running on one region after another, I know that only one region is getting impacted at a time. When we run `major_compact` on a table, does it also take care of doing it region by region internally or it starts compactions on all the regions together?